# Is there a tool that will tell me why my hard drive is spinning up?

Tags: ssd, spindown

I have my OS installed on a small SSD and most of my data on a large HDD. My HDD will spin up every fifteen minutes or so even if I am not doing anything. I want to find out who is causing it to spin up so I can either move its stuff back or tell it to stop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `find` to find out which files have been accessed. E.g. `find /hdd/mount/path -cmin -15` will show you the files accessed in the last 15 minutes. Of course you have to enter the right path where your HDD is mounted. Otherwise it will look for files in the whole system. Maybe this gives you a hint. If you have no idea what process accessed the files, you can also [find out exactly](https://superuser.com/questions/33781/see-history-of-who-all-opened-a-particular-file).

Another tool that could be usefull is `iotop`. You have to install it first:

```
sudo apt-get install iotop
```

Then you can run

```
sudo iotop -m /hdd/mount/path
```

to see which processes are accessing a specific mount path or

```
sudo iotop -f /path/to/file
```

to see which processes are accessing a specific file. The downside is that you have to watch it and wait for the access to happen.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. A note on `find`: `-cmin` will show only files that were changed where `-amin` shows files that were just accessed as well. That's what worked for me.